# Burn or add wiki for the [nop] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-disambiguation, tag-wiki

I was just about to ask my first question about a tool called **nop-commerce** (for which there is a tag [nopcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nopcommerce)). I also noticed that there was a [nop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nop) tag with very few questions.

I took a quick look and there seemed to be about 10 questions or so that were about [nopcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nopcommerce) and some others about assembly / raw machine level stuff. I believe the questions about nop-commerce was due to lack of any wiki information (and assume that it's supposed to be something assembly related but not knowing about it I don't want to update the wiki entry). Having only 16 questions left (after I've removed the nop-commerce ones) I wonder if the tag is still necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the cleanup.

Now, to [nop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nop): It does not hurt any, and is actually useful (arguably more than quite a lot in the long tail of tags.

Especially for the assembly-freaks (sometimes me), but the concept transcends languages.

Comment: If you understand the tag - would you be able to add a brief wiki info on what it actually means? Hopefully that'll stop it's misuse...

Comment: That will need a bit longer, as I must leave just now. Will look at it when back.

Comment: I've made a start on the tag wiki - check it over and carry on as appropriate (there had been another nopcommerce question tagged with it since this question was asked, so it was time to define it).

Comment: @slugster: Looked it over and added my own contribution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a useful tag with a legitimate, well-understood meaning; it shouldn't be removed.

I've merged the following tags together:

- [nop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nop)
- [noop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/noop)
- [no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-op)

with the latter as the "primary" tag (the others are all synonyms of it). I've also manually merged together the wikis, plus some of my own tweaks.